# Create an array of integers, given the first integer and size in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an integer, and would like to create an array of integers with a set number of additional entries

For example, there is

first = 8

size = 4

and the result would be [8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick for you:

```
(first..(first+size)).to_a if size > 0
```

Comment: You could tighten it up a bit using splat: `[*first..first + size] if size > 0`

Comment: @O-I without benchmarking I don't know which would actually be faster. Meanwhile, I personally find splat to be less readable although I fully acknowledge that that's a matter individual preference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a range to do this fairly easily:

```
first = 8
size = 4
a = (first...(first+size)).to_a
```

Note that that gives you an array of size **5**, not 4, but that's what you asked for.

Comment: You need double-dot, not triple.  The triple-dot range operator is non-inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

`first.upto(first + size)`, range syntax is more appropriete for constant ranges.

Comment: That's an iterator, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
Range.new(first, first + size - 1).to_a 
# returns [8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.new(size + 1){|i| i + first}
```

Answer (score -1):

`(first..Float::INFINITY).take(size + 1)`